# PDF text chunked by page - native way to group results by source pdf?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

As a user, I want to search a corpus of PDF documents, and see unique PDFs per row in the results set.

We are currently chunking our PDF documents' text by page. Each page becomes a single 'document' in our cognitive search index. These chunks may get smaller when we implement vector search.

Is there a native way to group the search results by source PDF, instead of getting one search-result row for each page of that source PDF?

Our current workaround is to load the entire result set and group by source PDF in-memory using `metadata_storage_path` index field.